# How can I store user input inside a text file in perl?

Tags: perl, file, input, printing, prompt

I'm trying to create a text file that will store user input such as their initials.  This code will prompt the user for the information and create a text file but the text file remains empty. How can I get the information to store itself inside the text file? I've tried using the variant $initials but it's not storing the information. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter users initials: ";
my $initials = <STDIN>;    # prompts user for input

open( MYFILE, '>>initials.txt' );    #creates file initials.txt
while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    print MYFILE $initials;
}
close(MYFILE);
```

Comment: I don't think you can read in a file that you open for appending, `>>`. Why are you reading in the file line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the while loop or `chomp`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter users initials: ";
my $initials = <STDIN>;    # prompts user for input

open( MYFILE, '>>initials.txt' );    #creates file initials.txt
print MYFILE $initials;
close(MYFILE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will append text from $initials to end of the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter users initials: ";
my $initials = <STDIN>; # prompts user for input 

open my $fh, '>>', 'initials.txt' or die $!; #creates file initials.txt
print $fh $initials;
close $fh;
```